# Invalid argument to unary operator in R

Tags: r, error, column

I want to calculate the rate of change in Maximum Temperature (of 2 yrs) for a spatial data. The rate of change of maximum temperature for the 2 years data (say 2021 & 2019) is calculated as:- [{(Maxm Temperature at 2021-Maxm Temperature at 2029)/2 years} *100]. I have the following attribute data to be worked on:-
[image]
I used the following code for this purpose:-

```
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
setwd("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/IEM")
BagmatiDstrtWeather<-st_read("BagmatiDistrictWeather.shp")
BagmatiDstrtWeather<-st_set_crs(BagmatiDstrtWeather,'+init=EPSG:4326')
BagmatiDstrtWeather$RateofChangeinMaxm.Temperature<-{(BagmatiDstrtWeather[,5]- 
BagmatiDstrtWeather[,9])*50}
```

However, the errors displays as:-

```
Error in -Vec : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Why it is not calculating?

Comment: You should not use curly braces `{}`, that’s not R. Use `()` instead

Comment: @dieghernan, still its showing the same error using this code:-`BagmatiDstrtWeather$RateofChangeinMaxm.Temperature<-((BagmatiDstrtWeather[,5] - BagmatiDstrtWeather[,9]))*50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, so when you do this:

```r
BagmatiDstrtWeather[,5]
```

You get something like this:

```r
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 10.11197 ymin: 48.97744 xmax: 12.11549 ymax: 49.77007
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
   MaxTem21                           geom
1  3.565788 POLYGON ((11.03021 49.53537...
2 10.700198 POLYGON ((11.07981 49.33928...
3 19.838934 POLYGON ((10.69735 49.43627...
4  1.731720 POLYGON ((10.92734 49.76843...
5 19.248068 POLYGON ((12.11549 49.54795...
```

What is going on is that in `sf` the `GEOMETRY` is sticky, meaning that you don't remove the geometry so easily. So your code is failing because the code is asking to perform a substraction of columns AND geometries.

You can fix this easily just using the `$NAME_OF_COLUMN` operator instead of `[, number_of_column]` as you are doing. That is also safer, as cols order may change but col names changes only if the user do it explicitily.

See a reprex. **Please note that as you didn't provide any kind of data** I had to recreate one for this, so adapt the code to your data.

```r
library(sf)

# Create a mock dataset

geom <- st_geometry(giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(nuts_level = 3))[1:5]

df <- data.frame(
  dist_name = letters[1:5],
  shape_area = runif(5),
  shape_lenght = runif(5),
  created_at = Sys.Date()
)
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(45, max = 20), nrow = 5))
names(m) <- c(
  "MaxTem21", "MinTem21", "MaxTem20", "MinTem20",
  "MaxTem19", "MinTem19", "Prep.mm.21", "Prep.mm.20", "Prep.mm.19"
)

BagmatiDstrtWeather <- st_as_sf(cbind(df, m), geom = geom)

tibble::as_tibble(BagmatiDstrtWeather)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 14
#>   dist_name shape_area shape_lenght created_at MaxTem21 MinTem21 MaxTem20
#>   <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl> <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 a              0.347        0.395 2022-06-17     2.99   0.0407     6.29
#> 2 b              0.249        0.800 2022-06-17     2.64  16.1       10.5 
#> 3 c              0.906        0.458 2022-06-17     5.92  11.1       14.0 
#> 4 d              0.399        0.556 2022-06-17    12.2    0.0986     1.43
#> 5 e              0.648        0.222 2022-06-17    17.3   18.3        4.31
#> # ... with 7 more variables: MinTem20 <dbl>, MaxTem19 <dbl>, MinTem19 <dbl>,
#> #   Prep.mm.21 <dbl>, Prep.mm.20 <dbl>, Prep.mm.19 <dbl>, geom <POLYGON [°]>
# End of mock dataset


# ------------------------------------------

# Check
BagmatiDstrtWeather[, 5]
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 10.11197 ymin: 48.97744 xmax: 12.11549 ymax: 49.77007
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>    MaxTem21                           geom
#> 1  2.986580 POLYGON ((11.03021 49.53537...
#> 2  2.638382 POLYGON ((11.07981 49.33928...
#> 3  5.917370 POLYGON ((10.69735 49.43627...
#> 4 12.201692 POLYGON ((10.92734 49.76843...
#> 5 17.318856 POLYGON ((12.11549 49.54795...
BagmatiDstrtWeather$MaxTem21
#> [1]  2.986580  2.638382  5.917370 12.201692 17.318856

# See the diference

# Operate
BagmatiDstrtWeather$RateofChangeinMaxm.Temperature <- (
  BagmatiDstrtWeather$MaxTem21 -
    BagmatiDstrtWeather$MaxTem19) * 50

head(BagmatiDstrtWeather$RateofChangeinMaxm.Temperature)
#> [1] -597.52513 -658.03292 -548.52102  220.67496  -38.34132
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>